# Existence of non-commuting matrices that both commute with a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules

Let $V$ be a (finite-dimensional) vector space over a field $k$, and let $A$ be a linear transformation from $V$ to itself whose minimal polynomial is not equal to its characteristic polynomial. I would like to show that there are two linear transformations $B$ and $C$ that both commute with $A$, but that do not commute with each other.

Since we don’t assume that $k$ is algebraically closed, I was trying to use the rational canonical form of $A$ to find $B$ and $C$. The fact that the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial of $A$ are not equal tells us that the RCF of $A$ is block-diagonal with at least two blocks, which are the companion matrices of the invariant factors of $A$. I also know that any matrix commuting with a companion matrix is a polynomial of that companion matrix. But this seems to pose an obstacle: if
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
C_{a_1(x)} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & C_{a_2(x)} & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & C_{a_n(x)}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then my initial idea was to construct $B$ and $C$ as block-diagonal matrices with components that commute with the companion matrices in $A$ but that don’t commute with one another, yet it seems that this is not possible since the blocks of $B$ and $C$ will have to be polynomials in the corresponding companion matrices, which will force them to commute anyways.

Is the rational canonical form not the right tool for this? Or am I just missing something that would make this approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose, the rational canonical form suffices. Let $A$ be already in rational canonical form
$$
A=\pmatrix{C_1\\ &C_2\\ &&\ddots\\ &&&C_r}
$$
where each diagonal sub-block is a companion matrix whose characteristic polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial of the next diagonal sub-block. Now consider
$$
B=\pmatrix{I\\ &0\\ &&\ddots\\ &&&0}
\quad\text{and}\quad
C=\pmatrix{0&X\\ &0\\ &&\ddots\\ &&&0}
$$
where $X\ne0$. Clearly, $B$ commutes with $A$ but not with $C$. For $C$ to commute with $A$, we need to solve
$$
C_1X=XC_2.\tag{1}
$$
Since $(1)$ has a non-trivial solution over $k$ if and only if it has a non-trivial solution over $\overline{k}$, the algebraic closure of $k$, it suffices to solve it over $\overline{k}$. As the characteristic polynomial of $C_1$ divides that of $C_2$, the two matrices share a common eigenvalue $\lambda$. Thus we may take $X=uv^T$, where $(\lambda,u)$ is a right eigenpair of $C_1$ and $(\lambda,v)$ is a left eigenpair of $C_2$. Now we are done.